How do I install Visual Studio 2019 (or 2017) Enterprise for 32-bit systems offline?
I need to install Visual Studio offline, can you tell me how I can do this?
I have a successful Internet connection, but I can't run the VS.exe file I downloaded I have a successful Internet connection, but I can't run the VS.exe file I downloaded here. -And I tried almost every method to solve this problem. but I could not solve the problem-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio

I installed .NET Framework 4.8 and the problem was solved.
